# Freeing a pointer to a string in a structure [in C]

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management, free

i'm trying to find the most efficient way to use the 'free' command in a program I made. Basically there are several structers, the first is called Operation. Here's how it's defined -

```
struct Operation {
    unsigned int ic;
    unsigned int dc;
    struct symbolStruct *externHead;
    struct symbolStruct *symbolHead;
    struct DataCode *dataHead;
    struct MachineCode *machineHead;
    int linenumber;
};
```

It has several pointers to other structers, let's take machineHead for example.

```
struct MachineCode {
    unsigned int row : WORD_SIZE;
    unsigned int line;
    OperandType *structure;
    struct MachineCode *next;
};
```

And OperandType looks like this -

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int numOfOperands : 2;
    unsigned int addrMethSou : 2;
    unsigned int addrMethDest : 2;
    unsigned int operation : 4;
    unsigned int extraWords : 2;
    char *firstOperand;
    char *secondOperand;
} OperandType;
```

What I want to do is to free the strings "firstOperand" and "secondOperand" in structure (which is in machineHead ) and then to free machineHead itself, I tried to write it down using the following code -

```
void clear(struct Operation *op) {
    struct MachineCode *mh = op->machineHead, *fmh;
    while(mh != NULL) {
        fmh = mh;
        mh = mh->next;
        free(fmh->structure->firstOperand);
        free(fmh->structure->secondOperand);
        free(fmh->structure);
        free(fmh);
    }
```

But the program crashes in runtime. Is there an elegant way to do it or do I have to make a pointer varibale of every type in order to clear the memory?

Comment: Also WORD_SIZE is defined as 15.

Comment: any clues as to what line it's crashing on?  what are the values of the fields of the pointers when it crashes?

Comment: "Clear memory" generally means that you write over everything first. Freeing memory just releases it so that it can be reused.

Comment: The clear is at the end of the program, so surely all is already written (I didn't want to bring up the entire code, it's way too long...)

Comment: Tip, consider in `void clear(struct Operation *op)`, what happens when `op == NULL` with `mh = op->machineHead`?

Comment: @bruceg, I'm using Eclipse but it won't save the values after crashing (even in debug mode), is there a way to force it to do so?

Comment: @chux, it runs fine, but I guess it's because "clear" won't even execute the "free" command.

Comment: Are you ensuring that the last list in the link has `next` set to `NULL`? If not, then `mh` will never be `NULL`.

Comment: Take into your consideration that the program will run just fine if i'll remove the following lines -
        `free(fmh->structure->firstOperand);` and
        `free(fmh->structure->secondOperand);`

Comment: @alvits yes, but i'll try to force both firstOperand and secondOperand to have a NULL value before assigning an address into them, as they are not always used.

Comment: nothing changed.

Comment: You completely misunderstood our comments.

Comment: In what way? I understand the idea that if i'll browse the linked list and the last element won't have a NULL in next, the program will never stop. When I allocate the data needed for a "symbolStruct" type, I always assure the next field is set to NULL (like I said, the program runs just fine unless I try to free both firstOperand and secondOperand)

Comment: Here's the entire code it that's helping - https://pastebin.com/u/MWarp

Comment: (clear is in main.c, but all the files are needed for the program to run)

Comment: @chux I think I caught your drift. I'll try to assure that I won't try to free anything if ph->structure is set to NULL

Comment: Allright, thanks for the help everybody.